# Using tween() as a tick function for d3 transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've found a number of posts on the subject of an equivalent "tick function" for d3 transitions but am struggling to get any of them working.  I have a node-hover function (in a force layout) that simply doubles the size of the circle being hovered...

```
nodeToHover.select(".outlinecircle")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(800)
                        .attr("r", function (d) { return (d.radius*2); })
                        .ease('exp')
                        //.tween('customTween', function() {console.log("hovering");}) 
                        .each("end", function(d){ updateLayout(); });
```

All I'm trying to achieve for now, is to output a message to console on every transition event (no idea if that's 1 every millisecond, but I'm assuming there should be many of them in an 800ms transition).

I read through the API and it seems that "tween()" should achieve this, although the code above simply outputs to console once per node hover (just like if I used "each()") - and has the same effect if I place it directly after "transition()" or at the end of the chain as above.

In case it's relevant, the reason I'm trying to do this is because as I'm updating the node size during hover, I'm going to need to update the position of the other nodes in the force layout accordingly (at the moment they do nothing during the transition, and just jump into their new positions right at the end of the transition).

Really appreciate any ideas on what I might be doing wrong- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a custom tween, you need to return a function from the function that you pass to `.tween`. This function will be called with the current state of the transition (as a number between 0 and 1) and is supposed to return the value of the attribute at that point. In your case, this would look something like the following.

```
.tween("name", function() { return function(t) { console.log(t); }; });
```

where `t` is the number denoting the state of the transition. The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#tween) has a slightly more complex example. There's also a well-commented example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636) that explains this further.

Comment: thanks Lars!  So am I right in saying that I should be able to include the tween() reference in the transition().duration() chain?  I've tried inserting the line you quoted in my existing code (before the "transition()" and after "duration()") and it always results in an undefined selection.  Looks from the example you referenced that perhaps I need to integrate with a ".call()" to a separate function containing the tween?  Not sure why that should be the case though.

Comment: You need to add this code after `.transition()`. What do you mean by "undefined selection"? A selection of what?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - when I was placing the .tween line you quoted after .transition() and before .duration(800) I saw this in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined".  But then I realised I just had to include a name before specifying the function and now it's working perfectly!!  Thanks again.  E.g. .tween("customTweenName", function() { return function(t) { console.log(t); }; })

Comment: Oops yes, I'll fix that.

Comment: No problem, thanks as always for the super-insightful help!